# Python Scripting, add hotkey with map type Mouse?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, shortcut

I want to add a hotkey by script. The regular Addon tutorial mentions how to add a normal hotkey. But i need a Map Type Mouse, left mouse button, with holding down a modifier key. And i run into trouble here.

My current code is

```
kmi = km.keymap_items.new("view3d.paint_select", map_type = 'MOUSE', type = 'LEFTMOUSE', value = 'PRESS', key_modifier = 'I')
```

And i get this error:

```
TypeError: KeyMapItems.new(): was called with invalid keyword argument(s) (map_type), expected (idname, type, value, any, shift, ctrl, alt, oskey, key_modifier, head)
```

map_type is missing in the expected list of keywords. But where else should i put it then? Is map_type not part of KeyMapItem?

Comment: I think there is no map_type parameter in the 'new' function. See https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_1/bpy.types.KeyMapItems.html#bpy.types.KeyMapItems.new. 'LEFTMOUSE' is enough to indicate this is from the mouse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> example to toggle *Properties > Scene > Simplify*:

```
import bpy

# operator
class ToggleSimplify(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "view3d.toggle_simplify"
    bl_label = "Toggle Simplify"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        context.scene.render.use_simplify = not context.scene.render.use_simplify
        return {'FINISHED'}

addon_keymaps = []
# register
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ToggleSimplify)

    # handle the keymap
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon
    if kc:
        km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='3D View', space_type='VIEW_3D')
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new(ToggleSimplify.bl_idname, type='LEFTMOUSE', value='PRESS', shift=True)
        addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))

# unregister
def unregister():

    for km, kmi in addon_keymaps:
        km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
    addon_keymaps.clear()

    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ToggleSimplify)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Also see: https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.KeyMapItems.html

Comment: Thank you, you were both right. It's enough to use type='LEFTMOUSE' . That's what i was searching for :)